# cadastro de dados via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando fazer cadastro de dados por `ajax` e os dados não estão indo para o `BD`.
Fiz um teste, direto, entre html e php e funcionou, mas `html`, `ajax` e `php` não vai.
HTML:

```
<form method="post">
```

**VENDA MÉDIA MENSAL**

**Venda S/Margem**

Segue os código `JQ` com `ajax`:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $("#salvar").click( function(){

        var dataString = $("form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/salvarCustos.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dataString,

            success: function(data){
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                if(data.status == 1){
                    $("#msg").val(data.status);
                    $("#msg").show();
                }
                if(data.status == 2){
                    $("#msg").val(data.status);
                    $("#msg").show();
                }
            },

            error: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

PHP:

```
@$vendaMediaMensal = $_POST['vendaMediaMensal'];
@$vendaSemMargemPercentual = $_POST['vendaSemMargemPercentual'];
$vendaMediaMensal = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $vendaMediaMensal)));
$vendaSemMargemPercentual = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $vendaSemMargemPercentual)));
$qryConsulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM custos");
$qryNum = mysql_num_rows($qryConsulta);

if($qryNum == 0){
    $qryInsere = "INSERT INTO custos VALUES('$vendaMediaMensal','$vendaSemMargemPercentual')";
    $insere = mysql_query($qryInsere);
    echo json_encode( array('status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Cadastro efeutado com sucesso!'));
}else{
    $qryAtualiza = "UPDATE custos SET vendaMediaMensal='$vendaMediaMensal'";
    $atualiza = mysql_query($qryAtualiza);
    echo json_encode( array('status' => 2, 'msg' => 'Atualização efeutada com sucesso!'));
}
```

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML também? Dá algum erro na consola?

Answer (score 1):

Vejo um problema na query. Falta indicar os campos onde esses valores serão inseridos.

Deve ser:

```
"INSERT INTO custos (`campo1`,`campo2`) VALUES ('$vendaMediaMensal','$vendaSemMargemPercentual')";
```

Comment: @Sergio, não uso, não coloco os campos da tabela e sempre funcionou.
Uso essa mesma linha de comando SQL sempre e funciona.
Estou achando que o problema é no JQ, pois testei HTML com o PHP e o cadastro funcionou.

Comment: @GustavoSevero a resposta é do Lelo Lenda e não minha. Podes colocar o HTML como pedi no coment na pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve ser pq vc está configurando o seu ajax para enviar json, só que com o código abaixo:

```
var dataString = $("form").serialize();
```

... vc está enviando "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (em termos de formatação é o mesmo que encontramos na querystring de uma url).

Vc deveria passar um objeto (ou JSON) no atributo "data":

```
data: { atributo: "Valor" }
```

E no PHP vc poderia pegar os dados assim:

```
$body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo $body->atributo;
```

Ou... Vc pode, simplesmente, deixar tudo como está e retirar o atributo "dataType". Nesse caso vai funcionar como o submit sem ajax.